# How do I animate the same rigid body multiple times?

Tags: animation, rigidbody

Hey guys I recently started to work with Blender. I want to crate a 3D logo animation in which a cube is jumping in forward direction.

At first I just wanted to animate the cube with keyframes but then discovered the rigid body function. When I learned that I can animate a rigid body I thought to implement this function into my animation for extra realism.

I animated the first jump with success by keyframing the „animated“ function on the rigid body. For upward and forward momentum the cube is animated and for the fall it switches back to a dynamic rigid body.

Now that I want to animate the second jump, when I activate and try to keyframe the „animated“ function, the cube automatically jumps back to the last location where the cube was last set on „animated“. So to say it jumps back to the position where it is in the air just before it turns back to a dynamic rigid body in the first jump.

Is there a way I can solve this problem? I simply tried by copying the keyframes of the first jump and paste them again on the timeline where I want the second jump to happen. But then the cube of course jumps back to the origin and the jump is in the exact same location.

Help is much appreciated as I was not able to find any source on this toppic. All the tutorials only cover one transition from animated to dynamic.

File: [<img src=https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Xz8kaaBD />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Xz8kaaBD/)

(Sorry for spelling and grammar mistakes. I am not a native english speaker)

Comment: Hello could you please share your file (only the useful objects)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I will try. I am very new to blender and also this community. I don‘t know how to share only certain objects but since the project is pretty small I will just upload it whole if that is okay.

Comment: The file should now be uploaded.

Comment: Oh ok I've never noticed this limitation, maybe you need to bake the first simulation in that case?

Comment: When it's animated, it goes where you tell it, and you tell it where to go via keyframes.  If those keyframes are not where it is, then it stops being where it is.  You could keyframe it where it is, which you could do, perhaps, by copying transforms from it to an empty, applying that constraint, and then copying back to itself.  Another way to do it would be to bake the rigid body physics to keyframes ("bake to keyframes" operation) and then run a new simulation.  Either way requires finalizing the earlier part of the physics, unless you want to script.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I will try if it works with baking keyframes.

Comment: Okay, so I baked the simulation to keyframes. After that I tell the jumping cube to be a rigid body again. That however gets into conflict with the keyframed animation again since it seems to calculate the animation together with the rigid body values. Hence the animation changes and the jump does not look good anymore. Is there a way where i can tell the cube WHEN to become rigid body again? So for the duration of the keyframed, first jump it wouldn't and when landed it would be a rigid body object.
Edit: Maybe I can solve it by telling the cube to stay animated for the the first jump?