# Rigid Body Object "animated" value resetting location and rotation

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I recently made a post about a project I am working on. **For context you can find the post via this link:**

**[How do I animate the same rigid body multiple times?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/286995/how-do-i-animate-the-same-rigid-body-multiple-times)**

I was able to solve the initial problem by baking the simulation to keyframes. After that, I made the cube to a rigid body object again. At first that interfered with the animation of the first jump but I solved the problem by giving every keyframe the animated value. Now I have a similat if not the same problem.

I tell the rigid body to be animated for the whole of the first jump as well as for momentum gain for the second jump. So far so good. I keyframed the initial location and rotation for the second jump, as well as the animated value. I then moved the cube into the air, keyframed location and rotation, unchecked the animated value and keyframed that aswell. As soon as I uncheck the animated value though the cube jumps back to the initial point for jump two.

Why does it do that even if I tell it to be in the air on the same keyframe? Anybody has an idea how I can solve this? I think baking into keyframes again seems obsolete as the problem will just repeat itself.

**Project File:** [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rigid body simulation does cache its simulation.

So all you have to do is "delete bake" and then "bake all dynamics" then you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Chris.
My days have been busy with some other work related stuff and I come back to this post only to find that the problem has already been solved.
I love this community already.

Comment: you are welcome!